# main.py => other computer => others can use main.py but no python installed, how?

Tags: python

How? I want my ***"Friend(s)"*** to play my number guessing game(idea from geeksforgeeks) made with pygame, but my ***"Friend(s)"*** don't have python installed on their computers. This question probably ask a lot, but like to hear some suggestionsツ!

Source Code: [Github](https://github.com/Pyzekiel/NumberGuess)

Comment: You cannot use a Python program without a some kind of Python runtime. Normally, you jsut package the regular CPython runtime with your program, there are various tools for helping you do this

Answer (score 2):

If it's about sending your friends a stand-alone executable, you can look into projects like https://www.pyinstaller.org/ pyinstaller.

It's as simple as

`pip install pyinstaller`

and then

`pyinstaller yourprogram.py`

Comment: ok I'll try that